# How to get textOperations and Get Result?

Tags: javascript, json, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I need to do a **"Post"** to get the **textOperations** and use this received value to do a **"Get"** and return the results.

I'm doing the **"Post"** however I do not get anything in console.log (), how do I get this **"id"** received and use it in **"Get" to return the results?**

**The API name is:**

> Microsoft Face API
>
> My Code:

```
function HandWriteenTextAPI(){

  // CHAVE DE INSCRIÇÃO DA API.
  var API_KEY = "";

  // Deve-se utilizar a mesma região em que a chave de escrição da API está
  // NOTA: As chaves de inscrições de testes são geradas na região "Westcentralus".
  var uriBase = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/recognizeText?";

  // Solicitar Parâmetros de Retorno do JSON.
  var params = {
    "handwriting": "true"
  };

  // MOSTRA A IMAGEM RECEBIDA DA URL
  var sourceImageUrl = document.getElementById("inputURLImage").value;
  document.querySelector("#imageReceived").src = sourceImageUrl;

  // Executa a chamada da API RESTFULL via AJAX.
  $.ajax({

    // Utiliza a uriBase para retornar os valores dos Parâmetros
    url: uriBase + $.param(params),

    // Solicita os Headers
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
      xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
      xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", API_KEY);
    },

    // Tipo do AJAX
    type: "POST",

    // Solicita o Body
    data: '{"url": ' + '"' + sourceImageUrl + '"}',
  })

  .done(function(data) {
    // Recebe o JSON e transforma em um Objeto
    var objJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    console.log(objJSON);



  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Mostra as mensagens de Erro.
    var errorString = (errorThrown === "") ? "Error. " : errorThrown + " (" + jqXHR.status + "): ";
    errorString += (jqXHR.responseText === "") ? "" : jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).message;
    alert(errorString);
  });

};
```

Comment: try `console.log(data)` before stringifying and parsing data to check what data you are getting and then probably check its type by `console.log(typeof data)` . Let me know the log outputs.

Answer (score 0):

When successful, the POST request responds with an HTTP 202, which typically contains no response body.  The URL is contained instead in the `Operation-Location` HTTP header.  Here's how you might extract it:

```
  .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // Recebe o JSON e transforma em um Objeto
    if (jqXHR.status == 202) {
      console.log(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Operation-Location'))
    }
  })
```